why branches are not in context of function?
I'm trying to achieve similar report structure for gcov/gcovr as available by Cantata++.
MC/DC is ´now out of scope'.
My basic confusion, is the general separation of branches from a function context.
This is in all available output formats.
What I'm missing? Is there any possible output option, which accumulate not only statement but also decision/branches information per function?
Tried all xml/json formats.

The problem here is the data source used by gcovr. Gcovr knows where each function starts, but not which coverage counters are part of that function. Gcovr cannot assume that a function contains everything up to the next function, because there can be multiple functions on one line, and nested functions (like C++ lambdas). So you can get per-file coverage summaries, but not per-function summaries. The data is technically available, but not in a format that is easy for gcovr to access.

brilliant answer. Thanks
